# How can I “Delete All” from Inbox mail folder?

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

Is there a way to mass delete compiled list of emails on iOS devices (like can be done in os x)? I only know two options: select individually & swipe "left" and from bottom select "edit", then selecting each message individually. I tried solution described in similar question without success (described as iOS 7).

Answer (score 7):

*This was the only way at the time in iOS 8 - for newer iOS [possibly 13 onwards but unconfirmed], see [iPhone/iPad Mail - rapid mass delete](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391418/iphone-ipad-mail-rapid-mass-delete)*

---

- If it is not already showing, from your Mailboxes view, select Edit & check the All Trash option. This will then be added to the bottom of your Mailboxes list.  ***Needed later.***

[image]

- From All Inboxes, or your chosen Inbox, select Edit, then Mark, Mark all as read [seems to make a difference, toggle unread/read just so it gets the idea].
- Then Edit, check the first item, which enables the Mark, Move & Trash options.
- Hold Move & keeping it held, uncheck the item you just checked.
- Release Move.
- The Move options screen should appear.
  Select Trash.
- Wait until all items have been moved [the graphics seems to do it immediately, but experimentation has shown it can take a while to actually move, if there are a lot.
- Return to Mailboxes, select All Trash.
- Edit, Delete All, done.

*Caveat*... It seems that if you open any individual Mailbox after doing this, they are all returned. I think you may need to wait for the Settings > Mail... > [mail account] > Advanced > Deleted Messages, Remove... period to expire, before it becomes permanent.

Comment: THANK you for this. What an absolutely absurd, hacky ridiculous way for Apple to handle a very very simple task.

Comment: For sure - a simple 'delete all' even if it asked you 3 times 'are you sure?' would be preferable.

Comment: Works great for archiving all email matching a search on iOS 10! 