# How to delete all emails from inbox in iPad 8.1.3?

Tags: ipad, email, ipados

How do you delete all inbox mail messages in iPad iOS 8.1.3? It doesn't support prior move tricks many have posted as a method since it is unresponsive to the Trash target mailbox if you use the 'move all' trick.

Comment: There is a similar question that has been answered on Ask Different [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157019/how-can-i-delete-all-from-inbox-mail-folder-in-ios-8-1).

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't perform [this trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157019/how-can-i-delete-all-from-inbox-mail-folder-in-ios-8-1)... if you're that desperate, you can update to [iOS 9 Public Beta](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/) and this feature will become present.

Alternatively, you can jailbreak your iPad and get a tweak named *All Mail Actions* from the BigBoss repository in Cydia.

If you're not willing to do any of these, you're going to have to delete each and every email individually. There's no other way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to move all of you email messages in your inbox to your mail trash at once with the built in iOS mail app.

Is that what you want to do or do you want to remove all email accounts from your iPad?