# Delete all mail in the VIP mailbox on iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, mobile-mail

Without manually selecting them all, is there a way to delete all items that appear in the VIP mailbox?

I've seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/157019), but there's no `Mark All` or `Trash All` button in the VIP mailbox.

Comment: Trash all is new to iOS 9